# iOS (iPhone/iPad) SDK - Using a JSON parser with Twitter's user_timeline

Tags: ios, json, cocoa-touch, twitter

Ok, here is my code:

(appname)AppDelegate.h:

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @class TwitterViewContoller;

    @interface <appname>AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
        UIWindow *window;
        UITabBarController *rootController;
        TwitterViewContoller *viewController;
        NSMutableData *responseData;
        NSMutableArray *tweets;
    }

    @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITabBarController *rootController;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet TwitterViewContoller *viewController;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *tweets;

    @end
```

(appname)AppDelegate.m:

```
    #import "<appname>AppDelegate.h"
    #import "TwitterViewContoller.h"
    #import "SBJson.h"

    @implementation <appname>AppDelegate

    @synthesize window = _window;
    @synthesize rootController;
    @synthesize viewController;
    @synthesize tweets;

    #pragma mark -
    #pragma mark Application lifecycle

    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
        // Override point for customization after application launch. 
        responseData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
        tweets = [NSMutableArray array];

        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
                         [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=USER_NAME_ID"]];

        [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
        //[window addSubview:rootController.view];  
        //[window makeKeyAndVisible];
        return YES;
    }

    #pragma mark NSURLConnection delegate methods
    - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
        [responseData setLength:0];
    }

    - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
        [responseData appendData:data];
    }

    - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    }

    - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
        [connection release];
        NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        [responseData release];

        //NSDictionary *results = [responseString JSONValue]; <---This...

        //NSArray *allTweets = [results objectForKey:@"results"]; <--- and this was original code but it caused an exception,

        NSArray *allTweets = [responseString JSONValue]; //<-- So I used this instead.
        NSLog(@"THE ARRAY = %@", allTweets); //<-- THE ARRAY IS SHOWING FINE IN THE OUTPUT LOG
        [viewController setTweets:allTweets];
        [self.window addSubview:rootController.view];
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    }

    - (void)dealloc {
        [_window release];
        [rootController release];
        [viewController release];
        [super dealloc];
    }

    @end
```

TwitterViewContoller.h: (yes, I know I spelt it wrong - lol)

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import "SBJson.h"

    @interface TwitterViewContoller : UIViewController {
        IBOutlet UILabel *label;
        NSArray *tweets;
        IBOutlet UITableView *tview;
    }

    @property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
    @property(nonatomic, retain) NSArray *tweets;

    @end
```

TwitterViewContoller.m:

```
    #import "TwitterViewContoller.h"
    #import "Tweet.h"

    @implementation TwitterViewContoller

    @synthesize label;
    @synthesize tweets;

    #pragma mark -
    #pragma mark Table view data source

    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
        // Return the number of sections.
        return 1;
    }


    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
        // Return the number of rows in the section.
        return 20;
    }

    - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        return 80;
    }


    // Customize the appearance of table view cells.
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        }

        // Configure the cell...
        NSLog(@"THE ARRAY = %@", tweets); //<--ARRAY IS NULL <-- <-- <--
        NSDictionary *aTweet = [tweets objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];


        cell.textLabel.text = [aTweet objectForKey:@"text"];
        cell.textLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
        cell.textLabel.minimumFontSize = 10;
        cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 4;
        cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;

        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [aTweet objectForKey:@"screen_name"];

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[aTweet objectForKey:@"profile_image_url"]];
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        return cell;
    }


    #pragma mark -
    #pragma mark Table view delegate

    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
        /*
             <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" bundle:nil];
             // ...
             // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
             [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
             [detailViewController release];
        */
    }

    - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
        self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
        if (self) {
            // Custom initialization
        }
        return self;
    }

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
        // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }

    #pragma mark - View lifecycle

    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
        tweets = [[NSArray alloc]init];
    }

    - (void)viewDidUnload {
        [super viewDidUnload];
        // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
        // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
    }

    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
        // Return YES for supported orientations
        return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
    }

    - (void) dealloc {
        [tweets release];
        [super dealloc];
    }

    @end
```

The problem is that my UITableView is showing up but none of my tweets are. I have noticed that the "tweets" array in TwitterViewContoller (I know I spelt it wrong) is empty (the null problem is fixed) but "allTweets" in my AppDelegate isn't empty. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test to ensure that in your app delegate, the `viewController` property is not nil.  If you have miswired it in IB (I don't see any instantiation of it in your app delegate), it will silently fail when you call `setTweets`.

Also, if your view controller is visible and you re-set the tweets property, the table view won't update itself.  Instead of synthesizing your tweets property, write your own getter and setter, like so (you could also use KVO for this purpose if you like)

```
-(NSMutableArray*)tweets {
    return [[tweets retain] autorelease];
}

-(void)setTweets:(NSMutableArray*)newTweets {
    if(newTweets != tweets) {
        [newTweets retain];
        [tweets release];
        tweets = newTweets;

        [tView reloadData];
    }
}
```

As an aside, you should have `-tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` return `[tweets count]` rather than a fixed number, and it isn't necessary to implement `-tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` if your rows are all the same height -- you can just set the `rowHeight` property in IB or in code on the table view.

**Update**

If your view controller property isn't getting populated, it might be easiest to just load and add it manually in `-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` -- I think your current approach of delaying the display of any interface until the web request finishes is conceptually problematic.  What happens if the network isn't available?  Here's some code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // ... omitting the first few lines

    // let's make sure that we have the tab bar controller, at least
    NSAssert(nil != self.rootViewController, @"tab bar controller not hooked up!");

    self.viewController = [[[TwitterViewContoller alloc] initWithNibName:@"TwitterViewContoller" andBundle:nil] autorelease];
    self.rootViewController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:self.viewController];

    // this is now the Right Way to set the root view for your app, in iOS 4.0 and later
    self.window.rootViewController = self.rootViewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

There are a lot of ways that you can confuse yourself when you're starting a new project.  I like to customize all of my views to have hideous background colors at first so I always know if they're on screen or not -- using ugly colors helps ensure that I don't forget to change them later.

Comment: `viewController` did turn out to be null. Although I can't seem to figure out how to set it through Interface Builder. With MainWindow.xib I could just Ctrl+Click App Delegate to the window and select the IBOutlet but it doesn't seem to be as simple in TwitterViewContoller_iPhone.xib. Any ideas?

Comment: Additionally, my NSLog test under `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` no longer seems to be called (the NSLog itself isn't important - it just seems that `cellForRowAtIndexPath` isn't being called anymore).

Comment: Would `self.window.rootViewController = self.rootViewController;` work in earlier versions of iOS? (eg. 3.1.3).

Comment: `self.viewController = [[[TwitterViewContoller alloc] initWithNibName:@"TwitterViewContoller" andBundle:nil] autorelease];` is showing a warning which states `Instance method '-initWithNibName:andBundle:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')`

Comment: sorry, that should just be `-initWithNibName:bundle:`.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answers, although it's now throwing a `NSInternalInconsistencyException` because it "could not load NIB in bundle with name 'TwitterViewContoller'

Comment: You'll have to substitute the name of your view controller nib if it's not the same as your view controller class name.

Comment: Thanks ever so much! It is working! Just a final couple of questions: My tabs aren't showing up in my Tab Bar anymore. Anyway to fix this? And how would I implement `self.viewController = [[[TwitterViewContoller alloc] initWithNibName:@"TwitterViewContoller_iPhone" bundle:nil] autorelease];` if I had and iPad NIB version of TwitterViewContoller?

Comment: Both of those questions would be good candidates to repost as new questions.  If I've answered your original question, please consider accepting the answer by clicking the check next to my answer. :)

Comment: Okay, I will post them as separate questions just now! :) Thank you very much for all your help!! I would be lost without you! :)